# MATLAB matrix element wise multiplication optimization

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, matlab, matrix

I have to optimize a piece of MATLAB code. The code is simple, yet it is a part of a calculation unit, which calls it ~8000 times (without redundancy) (This calculation unit is used ~10-20K times in real cases). The whole MATLAB code is quite long and complex (for a physicist, like me), yet MATLAB profiler claims that the following segment is responsible to nearly half the run time (!).

The code is essentially multiplying elementwise every permutation of 3 matrices from 3 groups (A,B,C) and sums it up with some weighting. Group A has a single matrix, group B has 4 matrices and group C has 7.

I tried some vectorizations techniques* yet at best got the same run time.

Using the MATLAB profiler I checked the total time spent at each line (for all 8000 calls) - I wrote those in comments.

```
for idx_b = 1:4

B_MAT=B_Container_Cell{idx_b};

for idx_c = 1:7

    C_MAT = C_Container_Cell{idx_b}(:,:,idx_c); % 60 sec

    ACB=A_MAT.*C_MAT.*B_MAT; % 20 sec

    Coeff_x = Coeff_x_Cell{idx_b}(p1,p2,idx_c,p3);
    Coeff_y = Coeff_y_Cell{idx_b}(p1,p2,idx_c,p3);
    Coeff_z = Coeff_z_Cell{idx_b}(p1,p2,idx_c,p3);

    Sum_x = Sum_x+Coeff_x.*ACB; % 15 sec
    Sum_y = Sum_y+Coeff_y.*ACB; % 15 sec
    Sum_z = Sum_z+Coeff_z.*ACB; % 15 sec

end
```

end

Some prior knowledge -
A_MAT is 1024x1024 complex double constant matrix defined ouside the loop
B_MAT is 1024x1024 double matrix, essentially sparse (only 0 and 1 values, ones are ~5% out of total elements)
C_MAT is 1024x1024 complex double

Sum_x/ Sum_y / Sum_z were properly initiated
Coeff_X / Coeff_y / Coeff_z are double scalars
p1,p2,p3 are parameters (constant for this code segment)

Does anybody know why the most consuming operation is variable assignment?
(I tried to skip the assignment and replace C_MAT directly with it's expression, yet it worsens the performance)

---

**Vectorization attempt**
The techique I tried is to use cat, reshape and repmat to create 3 giant 2D matrices, element-wise multiply those and then put the all on top of each other (with reshape) and sum via the relevant dimention. The first matrix was A repeated 4*7=28 times, the second was the 4 B matrices repeated 7 times and the third was all C matrices spanned (=28 matrices).

---

**Sample Input**
The code on the following [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b934ffb10dede67fd0cf2b5fdf72cd2c) generates sample input files. The run time with these variables (on my computer) is ~0.38 sec (the original code+variables ~0.42, the difference in my opinion is because the real C Cell container is very large, so extraction takes more time)

Comment: `.*` operation is commutative (unlike `*` matrix multiply), so you can perform `A_MAT*B_MAT` outside the inner loop.

Comment: @BenVoigt it doesn't change much the performance.

Comment: You refer to vectorization techniques in your question, what have you tried?

Comment: Also, is `Sum_x` 0 before these loops? (same for `Sum_y` and `Sum_z`)

Comment: @BillBokeey yes to your second question, I'm editig the post to answer your first (my vectorization technique)

Comment: I'm posting a vectorized answer, can you test it and tell me if it gives time improvment? If not I'll delete it

Comment: @BillBokeey OK, thanks!

Comment: As you are talking about performance, please provide a fully reproducable situation (perhaps some extra code to generate input variables of the actual size, with their relevant properties). And of course make sure the runtimes match exactly with those inputs. If you indicate how fast you would expect it to go that could also help people to see whether certain tricks are worth trying.

Comment: The problem is that the code is already pretty fast by itself, but just takes times because of the big amount of times it is executed. The solution might be to change the whole code structure

Comment: I added code that generates sample variables and works with this code

Comment: If the container cells have identical sized matrices, why not use multi-dimensional arrays instead of the cell arrays that don't really support vectorized operations. Thus, `B_Container_Cell` could be replaced by `1024x1024x4` array, `C_Container_Cell` by `1024x1024x7x4` and similarly  `4D` arrays for `Coeff_x_Cell`, `Coeff_y_Cell` and `Coeff_z_Cell` each. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @Divakar, post it as answer for bonus. I tried it and it saved ~60% of the computation time (The self time of the function where this code segment was embedded was reduced from 150 sec to 60 sec).

Comment: See if the posted solution makes sense and works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the arrays in the input cell arrays are of identical sizes, it might be a better idea to have the inputs stored as multi-dimensional arrays instead of cell arrays to leverage MATLAB's vectorized techniques, which in this case would be `indexing` for extracting specific elements and `matrix-multiplication` for sum-reduction. So, when forming the inputs, we could look to form multi-dimensional arrays corresponding to the inputs : `B_Container_Cell`, `C_Container_Cell`, `Coeff_x_Cell`, `Coeff_y_Cell` and `Coeff_z_Cell`. Now, these are `1D` cell arrays with `B_Container_Cell` containing `2D` arrays and rest have `3D` arrays. Thus, when using multi-dimensinal arrays, we would have them as one additional dimension, i.e. they would be `3D` and `4D` arrays respectively.

To simulate their multi-dimensional array formats, let's convert the given cell arrays with concatenation using [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) along their `last+1` dimension, like so -

```
Bm = cat(3,B_Container_Cell{:});
Cm = cat(4,C_Container_Cell{:});

Cx = cat(4,Coeff_x_Cell{:});
Cy = cat(4,Coeff_y_Cell{:});
Cz = cat(4,Coeff_z_Cell{:});
```

Finally, the vectorized solution to use these multi-dimensional arrays and get the desired outputs -

```
%// Get ACB across all iterations and reshaped into (Nx28) shaped array
Ar = reshape(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@times,Cm,permute(Bm,[1,2,4,3])),A_MAT),[],28);

%// Use matrix-multiplication to sum reduce sliced versions of Cx, Cy and
%// Cz, to get respectived summed outputs
sz = size(A_MAT); %// Output array size
Sum_x_out = reshape(Ar*reshape(Cx(p1,p2,:,:),[],1),sz);
Sum_y_out = reshape(Ar*reshape(Cy(p1,p2,:,:),[],1),sz);
Sum_z_out = reshape(Ar*reshape(Cz(p1,p2,:,:),[],1),sz);
```

Please note that it doesn't look like the parameter `p3` was used.

Runtime test results (for listed sample inputs) -

```
--------------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 2.412417 seconds.
--------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 1.572035 seconds.
```

Comment: Storing the matrices in multidimentional arrays saved a lot of time (even with double loop structure). I'll try the vectorization as well, though you rightfully earned the bounty (I can't award it yet, until 24 hours past from setting the bounty)

Comment: @Alexander No hurry there. Make sure it works and is efficient enough for you. Also, would love to hear about the runtime numbers of the vectorized approach against the double loopy structure.

Comment: It's quite funny that any vectorized version is always slower for at least 20%. Even after changing more the structure of the variables to optimize memory use for bsxfun - it was still slower. This piece of code was meant to be double looped.

Comment: @Alexander One important thing to note here is that the reduction is along just 28 elements `(4x7)`. So, maybe that's not big enough to compensate for the time spent in forming that big array `Ar` with `bsxfun`.